# Is there software that can optimally determine how to cut sheets of plywood for a project?

Tags: woodworking

I want to build some porch planters out of sheets of plywood, but I'm trying to minimize the number of sheets of plywood I buy.

Is there software that will let me enter all my planter designs and then have it spit out the sheets of plywood with their cuts? Does software exist that converts a project design/CAD('ish) drawing to [bill of materials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials)?

Answer (score 5):

I have used [Cut List](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/cutlist.htm) in the past when building speaker enclosures.

Comment: That looks handy. Please follow [diy.se] guidelines by disclosing any affiliation you may have with the website you've linked to. Even if it's simply "I'm a happy user". Otherwise, some may consider this spam.

Answer (score 2):

There is plugin for sketchup that generates a cutlist for a project.

Comment: Please add a link so that people can find the plug-in easily.

Comment: I found [this](http://steveracz.com/joomla/content/view/45/1/), [this](http://cutlistplus.com/), and [this](http://www.srww.com/sketchup/cut-list-ruby-script.html) .  What is the preferred solution?